# Two windows office desk placement

Tags: office-layout

This is my office plan:
[image]

The dimensions are in cm.

Where is the best place to put the desk?

Comment: If you don't want someone to sneak into your office without knocking on the door, and stand right behind you while you are working, then there is an old question and answers here : https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/121788/how-can-i-set-up-my-office-to-discourage-people-from-standing-behind-me?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two of the general preferences are as follows:

1. Most people don't want the back of their desks (or their backs) to face the door. So,
   either the front or the side (left/right) of your desk should face
   the door. This way, you are aware of anyone coming into your office instantly, and look directly at the visitors' faces when you talk to them, which makes the communication more effective and professional.
2. Most people prefer the side (left/right) of their desk to face the
   window or to be right next to the window. This way, they can have a nice
   view of the outside/outdoor, and maybe even get some warm sunlight.

---

If you share the 2 preferences above, then one of the good ways would probably be to put the desk in the South-West corner of the office. The front of the desk would face North. The left side of the desk would be next to the second window, or close to the second window. (**Note**: the second window is the one near the number **385** on the floor diagram in your picture).